# Add app to business page (inside a personal account)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

For clients we use our Facebook tool that allows to post and monitor on business facebookpage.
Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error when I want to login as their business account:

To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using facebook as yourself.

see: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/233/screenshot20121214at125.png/

Ofcourse I do not want that. My business and Personal accounts needs to be separated.
Anyone know how to solve this problem? Deleting and starting a new business page is not an option (10.000+ likes)